# Backbone.Marionette How do I render the collection into the layout after the new model is passed?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

## View Code

```
@Portfolio.module "ProjectsApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Show.ProjectsLayout extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
    template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/list_layout"]

    regions: 
     projectSlidesRegion  : "#project-slides"
     projectDetailsRegion : "#project-details"
     projectListRegion    : "#project-list"

    initialize: ->
      console.log "ProjectsLayout initialized"

  class Show.Detail extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/_project_detail"]    

    modelEvents:
      "change" : "render"
      "add"    : "render"

    initialize: ->
      console.log "Show.Detail initialized"
      console.log this.collection


    #Project Slides


   class Show.ProjectSlide extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
     template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/_project_slide"]
     tagName: "li"

     initialize: ->
       console.log "ProjectSlide View initialized"
       console.log this.model.get('avatar')

   class Show.ProjectSlides extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView #CollectionView
     template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/project_slides"]
     itemView: Show.ProjectSlide
     itemViewContainer: "ul"
     initialize: ->
       console.log "ProjectSlides View initialized"

     collectionEvents:
      "change": "render"
      "add"   : "render"


#   Project Name List Code

  class Show.ProjectName extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/_project_name_on_project_list"]
    tagName: "li"

     events:
      "click a.project-link" : -> 
        Portfolio.AboutApp.Show.trigger "project-name:link:clicked", @model

    triggers:
      "click .project-link" : "project:link:clicked" 


  class Show.ProjectList extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
    template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/project_list"]
    tagName: "ul"

    triggers:
      "click .project-link" : "project:link:clicked"
```

## Controller

```
@Portfolio.module "ProjectsApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  Show.Controller =

    showProjects: ->
      projects = Portfolio.projects
      project = projects.at(0)
      @projectsLayout = @getProjectLayoutView()

      @projectsLayout.on "show", =>
        @showDetails project
        @showProjectSlides project
        @showProjectList projects

      App.mainRegion.show @projectsLayout

    showDetails: (project) ->
      projectDetailsView = @getProjectDetailsView project
      @projectsLayout.projectDetailsRegion.show projectDetailsView

    showProjectSlides: (project) ->
      console.log "activated showProjectSlides"
      projectSlides = project.get('project_slides')
      projectSlidesCollection = new Portfolio.Entities.SlidesCollection projectSlides
      slidesView = @getSlidesView projectSlidesCollection
      @projectsLayout.projectSlidesRegion.show slidesView      

    showProjectList: (projects) ->
      projectListView = @getProjectListView projects
      Portfolio.AboutApp.Show.on "project-name:link:clicked", (project) =>
        @showProject project

      @projectsLayout.projectListRegion.show projectListView

       #   Show Specific Project 

    showProject: (project) ->
      console.log project
#      @showProjectSlides project
      projectSlides = project.get('project_slides')
      projectSlidesCollection = new Portfolio.Entities.SlidesCollection projectSlides
#      console.log "showProject projectSlides: #{projectSlidesCollection}"
      projectSlides = projectSlidesCollection.reset projectSlides
      newProjectView = @getProjectDetailsView project
      newProjectSlidesView = @getSlidesView projectSlides
      @projectsLayout.projectDetailsRegion.show newProjectView
      @projectsLayout.projectSlidesRegion.show newProjectSlidesView

   # If I comment out the lines  newProjectView = @getProjectDetailsView project and  @projectsLayout.projectDetailsRegion.show newProjectView the projectSlidesRegion populates in the view with no issues, but no projectDetailsRegion updates

     getProjectListView: (projects) ->
       new Show.ProjectList
         collection: projects

     getSlidesView: (projectSlides) ->
#       console.log "projectSlides: #{projectSlides}"
       new Show.ProjectSlides
         collection: projectSlides


    getProjectLayoutView: -> 
      new Show.ProjectsLayout 

   # not sure if I need to explicitly pass the children objects to the view?
    getProjectDetailsView: (project) ->
      projectSlides = project.get('project_slides')
      new Show.Detail
        model: project
        collection: new Portfolio.Entities.SlidesCollection projectSlides
```

## Templates:

```
 list_layout.jst.eco:
    <div id="project-details"></div>
    <div id="project-list"></div>

  _project_detail.jst.eco:

    <img class="project-icon" src='assets/<%= @logo %>'>
    <h3><%= @name %></h3>

    <div id="tldr-wrapper">
      <article id="project-problem">
       <img src = "#" alt="problem pic">
       <h3 class="project-header">problem</h3>
        <p class="project-paragraph"><%= @problem %></p>
      </article>

      <article id="project-solution">
       <img src = "#" alt="solution pic">    
        <h3 class="project-header">solution</h3>
        <p class="project-paragraph"><%= @solution %></p>
     </article>
    </div>

    <!-- how do I get this to show when I click on the new project from the project's list   in the projectListRegion? -->
      <div id="project-slides"></div>
    <!-- end -->

    <p><%= @detail %></p>
```

_project_slide.jst.eco

```
<img src='assets/<%= @avatar %>' />
<%= @caption %>
```

## json object:

```
{
 "id":1,
 "name":"project name",
 "logo":"project-icon.png",
 "problem":"The project's problem.",
 "detail":"project's details",
 "project_slides":
    [
     {
      "id":1,
      "project_id":1,
      "avatar":"blue-disc.png",
      "caption":"what a lovely disc"
      },         
     {
      "id":3,
      "project_id":1,
      "avatar":"desktop.png",
      "caption":"yay computer"
     }
    ]
 }
```

When I first bring up the page, the project and the project's details along with the project list show up correctly. When I click on a project name from the projects list, I expect the projectDetailsRegion and projectSlidesRegion to be updated with the new project's attributes and the project list to remain the same. The project list is showing all the project names as normal. However only the the projectDetailsRegion is updated and the projectSlides is blank. How do I get the projectSlidesRegion to populate with the new model's project slides?

Answer (score 0):

## View

```
@Portfolio.module "ProjectsApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Show.ProjectsLayout extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
    template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/list_layout"]

    regions: 
     projectSlidesRegion  : "#project-slides"
     projectDetailsRegion : "#project-details"
     projectListRegion    : "#project-list"

    initialize: ->
      console.log "ProjectsLayout initialized"

  class Show.Detail extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout # <-- changed this to a layout 

    template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/_project_detail"]    

    regions: 
     projectSlidesRegion  : "#project-slides"


    itemView: Show.ProjectSlides
    itemViewContainer: "#project-slides"
    modelEvents:
      "change" : "render"
      "add"    : "render"

    initialize: ->
      console.log "Show.Detail initialized"
      console.log this.collection


#       Project Slides


   class Show.ProjectSlide extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
     template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/_project_slide"]
     itemViewContainer: "#project-slides"
     tagName: "li"

     initialize: ->
       console.log "ProjectSlide View initialized"
       console.log this.model.get('avatar')

   class Show.ProjectSlides extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView #CollectionView
     template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/project_slides"]
     itemView: Show.ProjectSlide
     itemViewContainer: "ul"
     initialize: ->
       console.log "ProjectSlides View initialized"

     collectionEvents:
      "change": "render"
      "add"   : "render"


#       Project Name List Code

  class Show.ProjectName extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/_project_name_on_project_list"]
    tagName: "li"

    events:
      "click a.project-link" : -> 
        Portfolio.AboutApp.Show.trigger "project-name:link:clicked", @model

    triggers:
      "click .project-link" : "project:link:clicked" 


  class Show.ProjectList extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
    template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/project_list"]
    itemView: Show.ProjectName
    tagName: "ul"

    triggers:
      "click .project-link" : "project:link:clicked"
```

## Controller

```
        # Show Specific Project 


showProject: (project) ->
  console.log project
  projectSlides = project.get('project_slides')
  projectSlidesCollection = new Portfolio.Entities.SlidesCollection projectSlides
  projectSlides = projectSlidesCollection.reset projectSlides
  newProjectView = @getProjectDetailsView project
  newProjectSlidesView = @getSlidesView projectSlides
  showDetailView = @getProjectDetailsView project
  @projectsLayout.projectDetailsRegion.show showDetailView
  showDetailView.projectSlidesRegion.show newProjectSlidesView # <-- All set; just needed a layout nested within a layout
```